# Django Rest API - ProgrammingError relation 'core_donation' does not exist

Tags: django, docker, django-models, django-rest-framework

Here is a link to my github repo: https://github.com/hertweckhr1/api_foodcycle

My user endpoints work great. However when I try to reach my endpoint localhost:8000/api/donation/donations, I get back the error:

ProgrammingError at api/donation/donations relation "core_donation" does not exist Line 1: ...n"."pickup_endtime", "core_donation"....: 
[Link to Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTYsD.png)

I have tried makemigrations donation and migrate several times. It says my migrations are up to date. Other posts similar to this, I have not been able to find a solution that works for me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Run these commands

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete all stuff in migrations folder(only keep `__init__.py` file) and after that do migrations again:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```